# How to get pid of last background process in SSH

Tags: bash, ssh

My shell script is run over SSH this way:

```
ssh -i mycert.pem testuser@myserver.com <<SSHBLOCK
pm2 logs --lines 100 &
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill $pid
SSHBLOCK
```

The script works as expected when on local server (not wrapped in ssh block). But when I need to get logs on remote server, $pid is just blank. Why is $! empty when used in the SSHBLOCK above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this problem because you mix local and remote variables.

When you write :

```
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill $pid
```

you attempt to read the last pid used on the local client.

You should write :

```
pid="\$!"
sleep 3
kill "\$pid"
```

to get the remote value.

Alternatively, if you only use remote variables, you could just quote your heredoc :

```
ssh -i mycert.pem testuser@myserver.com <<'SSHBLOCK'
pm2 logs --lines 100&
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill $pid
SSHBLOCK
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't know 'SSHBLOCK' is different from SSHBLOCK :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because the local shell (the shell you use to run `ssh`) will try to expand `$!`.

Put the here doc delimiter into single quotes to avoid local variable expansion:

```
ssh -i mycert.pem testuser@myserver.com << 'SSHBLOCK'
pm2 logs --lines 100 &
pid=$!
sleep 3
kill $pid
SSHBLOCK
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 2):

When you run it locally, your shell expands `$!` into the last backgrounded pid, as you expect. But as you've written it, variables including `$!` are being expanded by the shell in which you run the `ssh` command, and not by the remote host.

Think of your heredoc as being sort of similar to double quotes:

```
ssh user@host "pm2 logs --lines 100 & pid=$!; sleep 3; kill $pid"
```

The `$!` here expands to the last backgrounded pid ... of the local shell.

The easiest ways to fix this is probably to escape the `$` characters or single quote your heredoc marker to avoid variable expansion. One more option would be to put your entire "script" into single quotes:

```
ssh -i mycert.pem testuser@myserver.com '
  pm2 logs --lines 100 &
  pid=$!
  sleep 3
  kill $pid'
```